# Detecting the caller of a function in Scheme or Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

In Scheme or Racket is it possible to detect the caller of a function?

For example, I can write a function to test if a list is a list of atoms as follows:

```
(define atom? (lambda (x) (and (not (pair? x)) (not (empty? x)))))

(define lat? (lambda (l)
               (define latt?
                 (lambda (l)
                   (cond
                     ((null? l) #t)
                     ((atom? (car l)) (latt? (cdr l)))
                     (else #f))))
               (if (null? l) #f (latt? l))))
```

but instead of the above, is there a function like "called-by" to do something like this:

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((and (null? l) (called-by "lat?")) #t)
      ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)))
      (else #f))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to add some argument to the function, or make a loop via an internal definition as you did.  Other than that, there is no reliable way to find out the caller of a function.

But in your case, it seems like a good lack of feature -- using it for the above problem is pretty bad.  There's nothing wrong with the internal helper version.  (It's also quite similar to any other language.)

Finally, I'd expect `(lat? null)` to return `#t` since it *is* a list that has only atoms as elements.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I'm a little unclear what you mean by "Finally, I'd expect (lat? null) to return #t since it is a list that has only atoms as elements." Do you mean the empty list is considered a list of atoms or are you pointing out some error in my coding.

Comment: I mean that the empty list is usually considered as a list of atoms (or a list of anything you want) -- and doing that will eliminate naturally the difficulty that lead you to this question.