# Graph search with a predicate function which keeps track of hop limit

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket, predicate

The following code searches a graph and returns true or false depending upon the predicate function passed as a parameter.

The graph is represented in the form of an adjacency list.

Assume that the graph does not contain cycles.

Code:

```
(define (search predicate? key)
  (define value-list (lookup key))
  (if (not (empty? value-list))
      (if (findf predicate? value-list)
          #t
          (ormap (curry search predicate?) value-list))
      #f))
```

The loopup function is used to do a lookup on a hash-table and returns its corresponding paths.

The search function gets the paths and if found to be non-empty tries to find the element using the predicate function and if found returns true else calls search() for each element in the list.

This seems to work.

Now am stuck tying to achieve the following:

Currently the search function traverses the complete graph and applies predicate to all of its nodes.

I wish to create a predicate function which not only includes the element to be searched for but also includes the hop limit.

For example :
if hop-limit is 1 : The predicate function would be return true if and only if the search node is within 1 hop and false otherwise.

I wish to generalize the hop-limit for n without modifying the search().

Things i thought of till now for solving this:

1.I could change the search function to pass the hop count as a parameter and use that to terminate out of the recursion, However i do not wish to change the search function.

2.Count the number of number of nodes which can be visited with the given hop-limit and store that information inside the predicate function and for each call of the predicate function,decrement the count and if count hits 0 return false everytime.
(However i am not sure how to implement the above (maybe closures ?), nor do i think that this would work because the count could be used up for the longest node list)

3.If i could find the caller in the predicate function i.e if the caller is findf then don't increment the count,if the caller is search the increment the count present in the predicate and use that.
That led me to :
[Detecting the caller of a function in Scheme or Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961749/detecting-the-caller-of-a-function-in-scheme-or-racket?rq=1)

However that didn't help.

am stuck and out of ideas any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**:

A little clarification on why i felt that approach 2 wouldn't work.

The function search is doing a dept first search.

I think that the approach 2 wouldn't work for the following 2 reasons.

Let's Assume the graph

[image: acyclic graph]

Say Start Position is 'A' and the search element is 'I' with hop limit as 2.

Now the counter value = num of nodes which can be visited with 2 hop-counts starting from 'A'
That is :
Count = 0 (intially)

Within hop count 1 : 'C' and 'D' , count=2

Within hop count 2 : 'F','G','H','I' , count = 2+4 = 6.

Let's Start with 'A' the way the code would work is

Nodes visited (in findf) would be 'C' and 'D' , count = 6 - 2 = 4

Lets assume that the left half is taken first.

Now 'C' becomes the key and all of its sub-childs are visited

Nodes visited (in findf) would be 'F','G','H' , count = 4-3 = 1

'F' has no subclild so no probs.

'G' has one subchild so it visits 'K' and count becomes = 1-1 = 0.

So henceforth all iterations would return false because we counted the max-number of nodes if approach 2 is followed.

One way to solve it would be adjust the count properly, however i feel that we might end up doing a complete search of the graph for the element to keep track of the correct count.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your anticipated problem with approach #2? In particular I don't understand what you meant by "the count could be used up for the longest node list"

Comment: @pnkfelix:I have updated the question with the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat for this answer: I see the question as brain-teaser type puzzle; I think the *best* way to solve this is via approach #1 outlined in the question. But if we assume that we are not allowed to modify `search`, for whatever reason...

... and we assume that the `predicate?` that we pass in is allowed to maintain state *and* make calls to the `lookup` that is used in `search` (and is our essential representation for the graph), ...

then I think one can accomplish your goal, by having the `predicate?` keep track on its own of the hop-counts for all of the nodes that it has encountered.

Then, it can just query that hop-count table whenever it wants to know whether the node it has encountered is too far away.

Here's the code I've made to illustrate this:

```
(define (is-parent-of? maybe-parent maybe-child)
  (member maybe-child (lookup maybe-parent)))

(define (hist-capturing-pred root pred?)
  (let ((hop-counts (list (list root (box 0)))))
    (lambda (n)
      (let* ((parents (filter (lambda (entry) (is-parent-of? (car entry) n))
                              hop-counts))
             (min-count (apply min (map unbox (map cadr parents)))))
             ;; the `min-count` above represents a distance given what we
             ;; know so far. Its possible that we actually encountered `n`
             ;; *previously* via a *longer* path, in which case not only
             ;; will there already be an entry for `n` in the `hop-counts`
             ;; table, but it will have recorded a non-globally-minimum
             ;; hop-count.
             ;;
             ;; So, check if there is an entry for `n`, and if so, make
             ;; sure it holds the currently known minimum value.
        (cond ((assoc n hop-counts)
               => (lambda (entry)
                    (set-box! (cadr entry)
                              (min min-count (unbox (cadr entry))))))
              (else
               ;; otherwise, add a new entry for `n` to the table
               (set! hop-counts (cons (list n (box (+ 1 min-count)))
                                      hop-counts))))
        (pred? (map (lambda (entry) (list (car entry) (unbox (cadr entry))))
                    hop-counts)
               n)))))
```

And here are some sample calls in the DrRacket interactions window:

```
> (search (hist-capturing-pred 'A (lambda (h n) (display `(,h ,n)) (newline) (eq? n 'I))) 'A)
(((C 1) (A 0)) C)
(((D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) D)
(((F 2) (D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) F)
(((G 2) (F 2) (D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) G)
(((H 2) (G 2) (F 2) (D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) H)
(((K 3) (H 2) (G 2) (F 2) (D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) K)
(((K 2) (H 2) (G 2) (F 2) (D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) K)
(((I 2) (K 2) (H 2) (G 2) (F 2) (D 1) (C 1) (A 0)) I)
#t
> (search (hist-capturing-pred 'A (lambda (h n) (and (eq? n 'I) (< (cadr (assoc 'I h)) 3))))  'A)
#t
> (search (hist-capturing-pred 'A (lambda (h n) (and (eq? n 'I) (< (cadr (assoc 'I h)) 2))))  'A)
#f
>
```